# ¿Como enviar un map a otra pagina y recibirlo?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy enviando información a otra pagina **html** de la siguiente manera

```
window.location = "pagina2.html?data=" + data + ""
```

donde **data** es un tipo **map** con la siguiente estructura

```
data = {"data1":"example1","data2":3,"data3":true};
```

lo intento recibir de la siguiente manera en la otra pagina.

```
var paramstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
```

lo cual me retorna como resultado lo siguiente.

```
data=[object%20Object]
```

La **url como resultado es la siguiente:** pagina2.html?data=[object Object]

**¿Como puedo obtener los valores del map?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene a que no puedes enviar ciertos caracteres por url, una vez que la url esta asi **pagina2.html?data=[object Object]** ya no podrias tener de vuelta la información

Debes convertir el objeto a una string que se pueda enviar por url y que se pueda leer de vuelta

```
function objectToUrl(_obj){
    return `?${Object.keys(_obj).filter(key => _obj[key] !== undefined && _obj[key] !== null && _obj[key] !== '').map((key) => `${key}=${_obj[key]}`).join('&')}`
}
```

utiliza esta función mandadole el objeto ***data*** y te devolvera la cadena que puedes mandar por url algo como esto ?data1=example1&data2=3&data3=true

```
const parametrosGet = objectToUrl(data)
window.location = "pagina2.html"+parametrosGet
```

y para traerlos de vuelta deberas hacer un proceso inverso, trayendo los valores de la url, utilizando por ejemplo esta funcion

```
function getAllParameters () {
    // initialize an empty object
    let result = {};

    // get URL query string
    let params = window.location.href;

    // remove the '?' character
    params = params.substr(window.location.href.indexOf('?')+1, window.location.href.length);

    let queryParamArray = params.split('&');

    // iterate over parameter array
    queryParamArray.forEach(function(queryParam) {
      // split the query parameter over '='
      let item = queryParam.split("=");
      result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
    });

    Object.keys(result).map(key => {
        if(!key) delete result[key]
        else if(!result[key]) delete result[key]
    })

    // return result object
    return result;
};
```

cuando quieras recoger los valores de la url simplemente la ejecutas y te traera un objeto con todos los valores que esten en la url en ese momento, por ejemplo estas en la pagina ***pagina2.html?data1=example1&data2=3&data3=true***

```
const data = getAllParameters()
console.log(data) // {"data1":"example1","data2":3,"data3":true}
```

Comment: Gracias pero me lanza el siguiente error `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: Perdon, podias adjuntar la cadena que se queda en la url

Comment: Edite la pregunta. muestro toda la url que se genera al pasar a **pagina2**

Comment: Ah perfecto ahi me queda claro, edito mi respuesta

Comment: Ok. espero, Gracias